# Excel weekly fortnightly monthly budget if statement

Tags: excel

My spread sheet has a columns for expenses that are weekly, fortnightly and month. To assist myself I am trying to simplify everything back to a weekly amount using IF statement.
Example is Weekly (A1), Fortnightly (B1), Monthly (C1).
D1 needs to end with weekly amount overall.
A1 is $10 so if has a value show value otherwise leave blank because either B1 or C1 will have a value.
B1 is $30 so if has a value divide by 2 and show otherwise leave blank because A1 or C1 has a value.
C1 is $85 so if has a value multiply by 12 and divide by 52 and show otherwise leave blank because A1 or B1 has a value.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compound IF should do what you need (parens are to emphasize the calculation and are not necessary):

```
=IF(B2>0,(B2),IF(C2>0,(C2/2),IF(D2>0,(D2*12/52),"no values")))
```

Propagate this down through the column you want normalized to a weekly expense and it should result in something like this:

```
        weekly  fortnightly  monthly  normalized
item a   10.00                             10.00 
item b                30.00                15.00 
item c                         85.00       19.62 
item d                                 no values
```